# Incorrect time chart Chart.js

Tags: chart.js

I am trying to generate a time chart with some positive values and some negative. I am trying to achieve something like this. The issue occurs when I set the chart xAxes type as time.

[image]

But what I get is

[image]

Sample fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dilani_m/scxb7zpL/) with chart configurations.

```
                xAxes: [{
                type: 'time',
                unitStepSize: 1,
                time: {
                    'unit': 'day'
                },
                displayFormats: {
                    'day': 'MMM DD'
                },
                distribution: 'series',
                gridLines: {
                    display: true,
                    drawBorder: true,
                    drawOnChartArea: true,
                    tickMarkLength: 15
                }
            }],
```

Comment: did you double check x,y axis values?

Comment: Yes, you can see the chart configurations with values in my fiddle attached.

Comment: i can see graph transforming on value change inside data[] make sure the values in graph 1 matches graph 2

Comment: values are the same. checked. fiddle of correct chart https://jsfiddle.net/dilani_m/r2g6wdae/

Comment: you are not showing values of upper image

Answer (score 2):

Time series was not in correct order. Since it is a time chart, labels should be in either ascending or descending order.

changing the time to the below order fixed the issue

```
  data: {
        labels: [
        "2018-12-04 00:00:14.000000"
        "2018-12-05 11:45:14.000000",
        "2018-12-05 12:00:14.000000",
        "2018-12-05 13:00:15.000000",
        "2018-12-05 14:00:14.000000",
        ],
```